# Add a vertical line in XLXSWriter graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I need to add a vertical line to the excel chart similar to below image. The chart is developed using Xlsxwriter==1.2.9.

[image]

I am trying to pass a single value (passing a single cell range) to the values field and removed the categories tab.

```
chart.add_series({'name': 'Vertical Line',
                  'values':f"{sheet_name,2,5,2,5}",
                  'line': {'width': 2.5, 'dash_type': 'dash', 'color': '#9ED8D2'}})
```

Please advice.

Picture reference:
https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/how_to_add_a_vertical_line_to_the_chart.html

Comment: The `values` field should be a list not a f-string.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will duplicate the example from 'how_to_add_a_vertical_line_to_the_chart.html' fairly close.
When the date is changed in cell 'D4' the vertical line will move to the corresponding date on the x-axis.

```
import xlsxwriter


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('xlsxwriter_vline_chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

### Add the worksheet data to be plotted.
### Set column widths
worksheet.set_column(1, 3, 12)

### Common format
common_format = workbook.add_format({
    'border': 1,
})

### Add Headers
Header_data = ['', 'Day', 'New Sales']
cformat = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'bg_color': '#92D050',
    'border': 1,
})
worksheet.write_row('B5', Header_data, cformat)

### ID Column
id_data = list(range(1,16))
worksheet.write_column('B6', id_data, common_format)

### Day Column
dates_format = workbook.add_format({
    'num_format': 'd-mmm-yy',
    'border': 1,
})
dates_data = list(range(44774, 44789))
worksheet.write_column('C6', dates_data, dates_format)

### Values Column
values_data = [132, 128, 95, 115, 83, 87, 67, 97, 112, 84, 77, 97, 86, 77, 83]
worksheet.write_column('D6', values_data, common_format)

### Add Date for Vertical line position
vh_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'border': 1,
})
worksheet.write('C4', 'Vert line Date', vh_format)

vd_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'num_format': 'd-mmm-yy',
    'font_color': 'red'
})
worksheet.write('D4', 44780, vd_format)

### Create a new chart object [Line Chart].
chart_name = 'Chart Test'
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart.add_series({
    'name': 'Data',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$6:$D$20',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$C$6:$C$20',
    'smooth': True,
})

### Add 2nd series for the Vertical Line [Scatter Chart]
scatter_series = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})

### Set vertical line chart data and format
scatter_series.add_series({
    'name': 'VerticalLine',
    'categories': '=Sheet1!$D$4',
    'values': '=Sheet1!$D$6:$D$20',
    'marker': {'type': 'none'},
    'line':   {'color': 'red',
               'width': 1.5,
    },
    'y_error_bars': {
        'type': 'fixed',
        'value': 80,
        'direction': 'minus',
        'line':   {'color': 'red',
                   'width': 1.5,
                   'dash_type': 'dash',
                   }
    },
})

# # Combine both Line and Scatter charts
chart.combine(scatter_series)

### Chart customisation
chart.set_title({'name': 'Line Chart with Dynamic Vertical line'})
chart.set_size({'width': 580})

chart.set_x_axis({
    'name': 'Day',
    'date_axis': True,
    'minor_unit': 1,
    'minor_unit_type': 'days',
    'major_unit': 2,
    'major_unit_type': 'days',
})

chart.set_y_axis({
    'name': 'New Sales',
    'min': 60,
    'max': 140,
})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('F6', chart, {'x_scale': 2, 'y_scale': 1})

workbook.close()
```